# What is the PIC equivalent to AVR's ICP?

Tags: pic, avr, microchip, atmel

On many AVR devices (afaik every one that includes at least one 16bit timer), there is an ICP (Input Capture Pin) that fires an edge-triggered interrupt. What's the equivalent on a PIC micro? Does anybody know a site like http://www.avrfreaks.net/?module=Freaks%20Devices&func=devCompare where you can select PICs depending on number of pins or certain features.

I simply need the smallest, cheapest PIC that's available from my distributor that has something like an ICP.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Important property of AVR's ICP is that latches to current counter/timer value when triggered. What you describe is PCINTn (Pin Change INTerrupt) which triggers on both rising and falling edges; and regular INT(errupt) pins support triggering on either FALLING or RISING edge or on a LOW level. PCINT and INT is probably available on every AVR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microchip Advanced Part Selector](http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx) lets you pick Microchip microcontrollers much in the way as the link for the AVR devices you linked to.

One of the criteria you can choose is "Input Capture".

There is no Search button; the results are updated dynamically as you change the criteria.

Note that there are several PIC families -- PIC10, 12, 16, 18 (all 8 bit), 24 (16 bit), 32 (32 bit), dsPIC30/33 (16-bit with DSP).

Comment: I'll go out on a limb here and guess the OP is probably going to be most interested in PIC 16 and 18 devices.

Comment: I was indeed looking at the PIC16 family. Unfortunately, the microchip part selector only spits out a small fraction of the parts available but looking at the datasheets and searching for an edge selection bit in one of the timer configuration registers should do the trick. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

peep this link http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1002&mid=10&lang=en&pageId=74. It's a comprehensive chart of the diff types of PICs available and what features they have.

If you click the "change products" on the far left you can also look at PICs from diff't families, like the PIC18 series and others.

I'm using a PIC16LF1827 and it does indeed have input capture capability. Just look for Capture mode in the datasheet.

I know this is waay past when you asked but still hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a peek at the 12F617.  [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41302D.pdf).  This has a feature that isn't widely available on the 12F line, an enhanced timer with a timer gate.  Between this and a typical edge triggered interrupt, I suspect you'll get what you want.

• Enhanced Timer1:

- 16-bit timer/counter with prescaler
- External Timer1 Gate (count enable)
- Option to use OSC1 and OSC2 in LP mode 
  as Timer1 oscillator if INTOSC mode 
  selected
- Option to use system clock as Timer1

Comment: aaagh, lured into posting to a year old thread by a new response.  Apologies, but I'm leaving the new answer up.

Comment: Necromancy is allowed. Heck, there is evn a badge for it (new answer with +5 score on 60 day old question) so its infact encouraged.